# Blazor/Razor Components do something when bound value changes

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor-server-side

I have been researching this but finding a dozen answers that don't seem quite right. What I'm trying to do seems like a common use case with a simple answer that I'm not finding.

I have, below, a .razor file with a small form, with a Start DateTime and a Duration. I want to update the EndDate property when either of these change--primarily I was starting with the Duration `<select>` when I got stuck. (Ignore the Telerik stuff for now, except to understand that it gives me a DateTime value in the bound `startDate` property).

Using `@bind` in the `<select>` precludes using `@onchange` on the same element... so, okay, I probably want something that responds to the change of the property values anyway... Well, `INotifyPropertyChanged` is used for that, and I started down that road, but it seems out of place with this pre-existing data binding mechanism. I found documentation on `EventCallback`, but that seems designed for inter-component communication, not within a component and I would be shoehorning it in. I could define the setters on the properties, but that also seems old fashioned in context...

In Ember, I would have used dependent properties for this.  Am I missing the intended way to do this in Blazor? Is `INotifyPropertyChanged` the correct way to go here?

```
@page "/"

@using System.ComponentModel
@using System.Runtime.CompilerServices
@using Envoi.BlazorApp.Annotations
@using Telerik.Blazor.Components
<h1>Record Encounter</h1>

<TelerikDateTimePicker Min="@Min" Max="@Max" @bind-Value="@startDate"
                       Format="ddMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss" Width="220px"></TelerikDateTimePicker>
Duration: 
<select @bind="Duration">
    <option value="5">5 Minutes</option>
    <option value="15">15 Minutes</option>
    <option value="30">30 Minutes</option>
    <option value="60">1 Hour</option>
    <option value="120">2 Hours</option>
</select>

End: @(endDate.ToShortDateString()) @(endDate.ToShortTimeString())
(@(startDate.ToShortDateString()) @(startDate.ToShortTimeString()) + @Duration minutes)

@code
{

    private DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime Min = new DateTime(2006, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    public DateTime Max = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromDays(365.25*4).Ticks);
    public int Duration { get; set; } = 5;
    public DateTime endDate;

    private void UpdateEndDate() // How to get this method called?
    {
        endDate = new DateTime(startDate.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Duration).Ticks);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this seems to be an instance of not seeing the forest for the trees. Basically, I just needed to go with this set of property definitions instead:

```
private DateTime StartDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime Min = new DateTime(2006, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0);
public DateTime Max = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromDays(365.25 * 4).Ticks);
public int Duration { get; set; } = 5;
public DateTime EndDate => new DateTime(StartDate.Ticks + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Duration).Ticks);
```

So, there were I think two problems:

1. `StartDate` (nee `startDate`) was not actually compiling as a property... so I imagine Blazor was probably not catching changes properly.
2. I just needed to have a lambda-based property for `endDate` that computed the value... because of course I did. [Not like I could have that as a settable property and a computed property at the same time, right? If I want another way to override and set the end date as well, I'll have to have a separate `EndDate` (settable) and `ComputedEndDate` (lambda) that checks `EndDate`... which is perfectly reasonable.]*

### Edit

`*` And after writing this I later remembered... Actually yes, that's exactly what I wanted: like the many [right-triangle solvers](https://www.calculator.net/right-triangle-calculator.html) and [subnet calculators](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/) out there, I was originally imagining an interface where you could set any of the three values (StartDate, Duration *or* EndDate) and one of the other properties would update to match... and you can't really do that with this approach because each property is either writable and not updating, or updating and read-only.

It does not appear that Blazor has a baked-in way to do this. [This article](https://blog.jeremylikness.com/blog/2019-01-04_mvvm-support-in-blazor/) discusses a few ways to do it, mainly variations on the options I already proposed. So while my answer addresses the specific problem I got stuck on with one-way properties, the larger problem does not appear to have a quick and easy solution.